# Is it possible to implement IValidateSetValuesGenerator for script parameter validation?

Tags: powershell

In the example in the powershell documentation you need to implement a class, like:
`Class SoundNames : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator { ... }`

But, how can you do this in a script based cmdlet? (See "Parameters in scripts" in about_Scripts).

In a script cmdlet the first line must be `param( ... )`.
Unless "SoundNames" is already defined, then it fails with `Unable to find type [SoundNames]`

If this type is already defined in the powershell session, this works ... but I'd like a stand-alone script that doesn't require the user do something first to define this type (e.g. dot-sourcing some other file).

I want to define a parameter that accepts only *.txt filenames (for existing files in a specific directory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this in a (stand-alone) script, for the reason you state yourself:

- The `param` block (possibly preceded by a `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute, must be at the very start of the file (leaving [`using` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Using) aside).
- This precludes defining a custom [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) that implements the [`IValidateSetValuesGenerator` interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator) for use in your `param` block.

---

To **work around this limitation**, use a [`[ValidateScript()]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute) attribute:

```bash
param(
  [ValidateScript({
      if (-not (Get-Item -ErrorAction Ignore "$_.txt")) { 
        throw "$_ is not the (base) name of a *.txt file in the current dir." 
      }
      return $true
  })]
  [string] $FileName
)
```

Note that this doesn't give you *tab-completion* the way that `IValidateSetValuesGenerator`-based validation would automatically give you.

To **also provide tab-completion**, additionally use an [`[ArgumentCompleter()]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ArgumentCompleterAttribute) attribute:

```bash
param(
  [ValidateScript({
      if (-not (Get-Item -ErrorAction Ignore "$_.txt")) { 
        throw "$_ is not the (base) name of a *.txt file in the current dir." 
      }
      return $true
  })]
  [ArgumentCompleter({ 
    param($cmd, $param, $wordToComplete) 
    (Get-Item "$wordToComplete*.txt").BaseName
  })]
  [string] $FileName
)
```